# Get attribute from parent node when parsing XML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, filter

I have an XML similar to this (but less fake, not to reveal the true and boring nature of my hobby projects)

```
<day date="2017-01-01">
 <event>
    <name>Birthday party</name>
    <time>18:00</time>
 </event>
 <event>
    <name>Concert</name>
    <time>21:00</time>
 </event>
</day>

<day date="2017-01-02">
 <event>
    <name>Debate</name>
    <time>12:00</time>
 </event>
</day>
```

I would like the final output to be something like this:

```
Birthday party      18:00   2017-01-01
Concert             21:00   2017-01-01
Debate              12:00   2017-01-02
```

How can I pass the date attribute down to each event, which I'm parsing like this:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("event");
 for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("time")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  }
```

I know it should be possible to use getAttribute but I'm just not getting it to work properly.

Comment: You are missing curly braces in your `for` loop. Also it's unclear what the issue is... yes, you can use `getAttribute()`. What doesn't work with that, exactly?

Comment: @Tomalak Sorry, missed the brackets when copying, fixed now. I'm only getting ""null is not an object" when using getAttribute() because the attribute "date" isn't an attribute of the event tag.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode (Next time, please include the code that causes the error, along with the exact error message. It makes all the difference for those who read your question.)

Comment: @Tomalak Yes definitely, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another `for` to iterate a days. Something like this:

```html
var days=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("day");
for (i=0;i<days.length;i++) {
   events=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("event");
   for (j=0;j<events.length;j++) {
  document.write(events[j].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write(events[j].getElementsByTagName("time")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write(days[i].getElementsByTagName("date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried this and it gives me the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'days[i].getElementsByTagName("date")[0].childNodes')` Tried modifying the date like this `document.write(events[j].parentNode.getAttribute("date"));` and that gives me the date for all events but then all events appear twice, presumably once for each day in the XML.

Comment: `events=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("event");` here u need to do some changes: To get event only for one day. Something like this: `events=days[i].getElementsByTagName("event");`